# Error installing MySQL 5.6.16 from source on Debian

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mysql-5.6

These are the steps I followed:

1. Download `mysql-5.6.16.tar.gz` to `/usr/local/src`
2. `cd /usr/local/src`
3. `tar -zxvf mysql-5.6.16.tar.gz`
4. `cp /usr/local/src/mysql-5.6.16 /usr/local/mysql/`
5. `cd /usr/local/mysql`
6. created group `mysql` with user `mysql`
7. `chown -R mysql .`
8. `chgrp -R mysql .`
9. `cmake .`
10. `make`
11. `make install`

But I got an error running this command:

9. `scripts/mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data`

> bash: `scripts/mysql_install_db.sh`: Permission denied

I am doing all these steps with `root` user.

Any suggestion to make it work. Please provide me the full steps to install MySQL 5.6.16 on Debian by compiling the `tar.gz` file.

Comment: Maybe you need `sudo make install`  at step 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `scripts/mysql_install_db.sh` have execute permission?
(check with `ls -l scripts/mysql_install_db.sh`)

If not, you can

1. add execution permission to it by

   ```
   chmod a+x scripts/mysql_install_db.sh
   ```

or

1. run it using `sh scripts/mysql_install_db.sh ...`.